# spellcheck attribute does not work in Edge for text inputs

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Why does the `spellcheck` attribute work fine in IE but not in Edge for text inputs? Here is my code:

```
<input spellcheck="true"></input>
```

Text area spell checking works fine in Edge but not text inputs.

Or is there a workaround?

Comment: known bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13929893/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could use a single line textarea. 
`<textarea rows="1"></textarea>` 
see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccoq4aks/) as an example

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is only supported in EdgeHtml versions 15 and above (https://caniuse.com/#feat=spellcheck-attribute)

It won't work on input tags if you are using Edge with EdgeHtml of 14 and below.

See @msokrates answer for the workaround

Answer (score 0):

it works on input and texareas only; input must have attribute type='text'; to configure the languages you should go on microsoft edge to configuration languages; also it apperas not to work if you use only capital letters.